# database design and relationship between (course, semester,student) and (course,semester,subjects) and (course,semester,subjects,assessments)

Tags: database, laravel, database-design

what is the "right-way" to establish relationship? 
-(students) are filtered using  (course) or (course and semester).
-similarly,(subjects) are filtered using  (course) or (course and semester).
-(assessments) are filtered using (course ,semester,subject) or(course)or(subjects).

Currently i have course_id,semester_id in many tables. Would intermediary table make sense or just increase complexity?

Answer (score 1):

course - **course_id**,semester_id(foreign key),  etc.. etc..

semester - **semester_id**, etc.. etc..

students - **student_id**, etc. etc.

enrolment  - (**student_id(foreign_key), course_id(foreign_key)** ) => composite primary key.

*this is with an assumption that student can enroll only once. else add date/time as one more field

Assessments - (**assessment_id**, course_id)

Marks - (**assessment_id, student_id**, marks)

This is currently in 3NF. and it is good enough for you to query them individually.